# Get result of a linked server MDX query through EXEC into a CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, linked-server

i have a SQL query which uses OPENQUERY to execute a MDX query on a linked server, but that query becomes very large and OPENQUERY has a 8000 characters limitation. From what i searched, EXEC does not have such limitation, but i'm not able to get the results of it to use in my query.

Here's a simplified example of what i need to do (using OPENQUERY):

```
WITH MdxQuery (field1,field2,field3) AS (
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM OPENQUERY(my_linked_server, 'my_long_mdx_query')
)
SELECT * FROM MdxQuery
```

I tried to use variables like this:

```
Declare @TempTable TABLE (
     field1 varchar(max),
     field2 varchar(max),
     field3 varchar(max)
)
Declare @strMDX varchar(max)
set @strMDX = N'my_long_mdx_query'

EXEC sp_serveroption 'my_linked_server', 'remote proc transaction promotion', 'false'

INSERT INTO @TempTable (
    field1,
    field2,
    field3
) EXEC (@strMDX) at my_linked_server

WITH MdxQuery (field1,field2,field3) AS (
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM @tempTable
)
SELECT * FROM MdxQuery
```

But it throws a syntax error on WITH, since it's not allowed after an EXEC.

**EDIT**
It was also giving the following error:

```
The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "my_linked_server" does not support the required transaction interface.
```

This error was resolved by adding this line before insert:

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'my_linked_server', 'remote proc transaction promotion', 'false'
```

But i still cannot execute a CTE query after the EXEC.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a semicolon (;) before With.